# docker uid/gid mapping changes on different host

Tags: linux, docker, namespaces, cgroups

I have a docker container build on one system where uid = 1000 and gid = 300

When I then try to use that same container on the jenkins server these uid/gid are taken by different user and groups so when I try to execute commands in the container it fails due to permissions.

How can I run the container with the users mapped to the correct uid/gid

Comment: Fails due to permissions on what? Are you mounting a host volume? Isf so, do you require a host volume?

Comment: Yes im mounting a volume from the host into the container to run some build scripts

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to handle uid/gid mismatches with host volumes.

- open permissions up on the host directory, often considered bad by the security team, for good reason, but also really easy to do.
- build a new image for each host where it may run with different uid/gid
- switch to named volumes instead. If you don't need direct access to the volume contents from the host, this is recommended.
- fix permission problems with an entrypoint.

I go into more detail on some of these in [my DockerCon talk here](https://rawgit.com/sudo-bmitch/dc2018/master/faq-stackoverflow-lightning.html#41).

There's also another example of the entrypoint solution where I configured a Jenkins container to fix the docker gid to match the mounted docker socket: https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/jenkins-docker

Comment: Im not using jenkins in a container, jenkins is invoking a container in a pipeline step which means the files in the workspace are owned by jenkins:jenkins not my 1000:300, I've just chowned the workspace for now to be owned by the uid/gid for the build to work, but I guess I want to map jenkins:jenkins to the uid:gid in the container can this be done with userns-remap?

Comment: User namespaces will not help, the reason they are disabled by default is because they break host mounts even further. The links provided are not a copy and paste of code you can use as is, but an example of a technique you can use to adjust the container uid/gid to match the uid/gid from a host volume mount.

Comment: Ok simplest option for me was to replicate the group gid on the host machine add jenkins into that group, then chmod -Rf  g+rwx workspace